# SwiftUI - Scroll a list to a specific element controlled by external variable

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a List populated by Core Data, like this:

```
@EnvironmentObject var globalVariables : GlobalVariables
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var coreDataContext

@FetchRequest(fetchRequest: Expressao.getAllItemsRequest())
private var allItems: FetchedResults<Expressao>


var body: some View {
  ScrollViewReader { proxy in
    List {
      ForEach(allItems,
        id: \.self) { item in
          Text(item.term!.lowercased())
          .id(allItems.firstIndex(of:item))
          .listRowBackground(
            Group {
              if (globalVariables.selectedItem == nil) {
                Color(UIColor.clear)
              } else if item == globalVariables.selectedItem {
                Color.orange.mask(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
              } else {
                nextAlternatedColor(item:item)
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } 
  }
```

Every time a row is selected it changes color to orange. So, you see that the color is controlled by an external variable located in `globalVariables.selectedItem`.

I want to be able to make the list scroll to that element on `globalVariables.selectedItem` automatically.

How do I do that with `ScrollViewReader`?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo of possible approach - `scrollTo` can be used only in closure, so the idea is to create some background view depending on row to be scrolled to (this can be achieved with `.id`) and attach put `.scrollTo` in `.onAppear` of that view.

Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14.

```
struct DemoView: View {
    @State private var row = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            // button here is generator of external selection
            Button("Go \(row)") { row = Int.random(in: 0..<50) }


            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                List {
                    ForEach(0..<50) { item in
                        Text("Item \(item)")
                            .id(item)
                    }
                }
                .background(         // << start !!
                    Color.clear
                        .onAppear {
                            withAnimation {
                                proxy.scrollTo(row, anchor: .top)
                            }
                        }.id(row)
                )                   // >> end !!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for some reason, doing that made the CPU skyrocket. Now, scrolling the list makes the CPU peak to 100%. Selecting a row is sluggish....

Comment: Hmm... on provided demo? Works fine here... sometimes momentary up to 30%, but usually not more than 5%.

Comment: ok, I have managed to get rid of the 100% CPU problem. Now, like yours, I see a peak at 30%, sometimes 50% if I scroll the list fast. I think SwiftUI has a problem there. Anyway, I will accept your answer and research more.